# Reduce the size of soft keyboard on edit text click

Tags: applications, keyboard

Usually the soft keyboard fits to the screen size in both portrait and land scape mode. I am developing an app, in that i have an edit text. On edit text click "Is it possible to reduce the width of soft keyboard on land scape mode?". Please guide me through this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: @GokulNC Sorry for framing my question in wrong way. I have updated the question. Please go through it.

Answer (score 1):

That depends of the keyboard app. Swiftkey, for example, allows the size adjustement of the keyboard in landscape mode.

Comment: Sorry for framing my question in wrong way. I have updated the question. Please go through it. I am asking about the default virtual key board that pop's up in android device.

Comment: No, as I said, the size of the keyboard depends of the keyboard app. You can't modify thay from your own app. You could do an in-app keyboard if you are capable of doing so, and if it is worth it.